# If regEx is bad for matching XML, what is the correct way?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I was trying to do a simple string delete in XML.

I want to delete something like the following.

```
<A>
    <B>Test Name</B>
</A>
```

Has to work with all possible XML, though.

```
<Test><A><B>Test Name</B></A></Test>
<Test ><A ><B >Test Name</B ></A ></Test >

<Test>
   <A>
       <B>Test Name</B>
   </A>
</Test>
```

etc, etc.

The regularEX I got so far, is simply:

```
<A>\s*(\r\n|\r|\n)*\s*<B>Test Name<\/B>\s*(\r\n|\r|\n)*\s*<\/A>
```

Everyone always says regEx is bad for match XML, which it clearly is.  So what should I use instead.

GC_

Comment: probably an xml parser?

Comment: For example, https://www.baeldung.com/java-xml, which covers pretty much all of them.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I would like something light weight. I don't really want to parse the whole xml, just to delete one line.

Comment: That's not one line, that's an element and its children. And therein lies one of the many problems with a naive regexapproach.

Comment: XSLT is the best for such tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach for this case would be using XSLT. And even with XSLT-1.0 this is simple (You can use the Java XSLT-processor, linux'es `xsltproc` or any other XSLT processor; every XSLT processor supports at least XSLT-1.0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  
  <!-- identity template - matches everything except the things matched by other templates -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
 
  <!-- Removes the elements you do not want -->
  <xsl:template match="A[B[normalize-space(.)='Test Name']]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output of your sample case (with a hypothetical root element) would be

```
<Test/>
<Test/>
<Test/>
```

Trying to use RegEx would be error-prone and no good-practice at all.
Why would you make it complicated if it could be so easy?